# Is there any online compiler API such that if I input the source code, it would return the results (or any errors) upon compilation?

Tags: web-deployment, online-compilation

I am building an online code storage platform for competitive programmers and need the code be executable on site. So I would require some online compilers which if provided with source code may return the results.
**N.B: The compiler IDE itself need not be visible, I just want the results.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answers. HackerEarth provides such facilities. Try out the following links - [HackerEarth V3](https://www.hackerearth.com/docs/wiki/developers/v3/)

And if theres anyone working on Node.js, explore this [HackerEarth - Node.js](https://github.com/tarungarg546/HackerEarth-node)
Thanks anyone who tried to help.

Comment: The link given in the answer is outdated please check https://www.hackerearth.com/docs/wiki/developers/v4/

Answer (score 1):

I have used https://rextester.com/main
Its free and almost every language available

Edit : its paid now. Its seems to be author didn't get much donation.

Comment: This api is not free :(

Comment: Yes, right now it's paid now.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried JDoodle Compiler API - https://www.jdoodle.com/compiler-api/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to a free compiler API (as of march 2023), check out this compiler:
https://github.com/Jaagrav/CodeX-API

There are not so many languages supported, but the more popular ones are there. Also, the API is not the fastest, but does the job pretty well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).